# how to make uniformgrid vertically

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, itemspanel, uniformgrid

I'm using `UniformGrid` and it's making the items display horizontally. Is there a way to make it display vertically?

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean `<UniformGrid Rows="3" />`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The WPF `UniformGrid` layout is horizontal only, e.g.:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Perhaps you could use a `WrapPanel` instead and just set the `ItemHeight` and `ItemWidth` to your desired grid size and set the `Orientation` to `Orientation.Vertical`.

Or you could create a derived `UniformGrid` to handle `Orientation`, there is a good example [on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/104b9cb8-3e1a-4e2e-ac62-4f9b32cc21f0).

This one will display:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: The first source code in the link working fine which do what you want, the updated source code doesn't, use the first one.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a bit late to the party - but for anyone else searching for a solution, the following works.

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1" />
```

Comment: What if we want a free-form grid without Columns/Rows specified?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit latER to the party, but for posterity's sake:

I'm just starting out with xaml and came across this problem today. For simplicity's sake, I ended up wrapping single-column UniformGrids in a multi-column, single-row UniformGrid:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="3">
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <!--multiple child elements-->
    </UniformGrid>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <!--multiple child elements-->
    </UniformGrid>
    <UniformGrid Columns="1">
        <!--multiple child elements-->
    </UniformGrid>
</UniformGrid>
```